# restructure array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following source array which I'm trying to restructure using group_name to give me the require output below.

Any help or pointers appreciated.
Thanks, Lk

Source:

```
Array
(
[field_a] => Array
    (
        [type] => text
        [group_name] => 
    )

[field_b] => Array
    (
        [type] => number_integer
        [group_name] => group_other
    )

[field_c] => Array
    (
        [type] => text
        [group_name] => 
    )

[field_d] => Array
    (
        [type] => link
        [group_name] => group_web_links
    )

[field_e] => Array
    (
        [type] => link
        [group_name] => group_web_links
    )

[field_f] => Array
    (
        [type] => text
        [group_name] => group_web_links
    )

)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[group_other] => Array
    (
        [field_b] => Array
           (
               [type] => number_integer
               [group_name] => group_other
           )
    )

[group_web_links] => Array
    (
        [field_d] => Array
            (
                [type] => link
                [group_name] => group_web_links
            )

        [field_e] => Array
            (
                [type] => link
                [group_name] => group_web_links
            )

        [field_f] => Array
            (
                [type] => text
                [group_name] => group_web_links
            )
    )

[field_a] => Array
    (
        [type] => text
        [group_name] => 
    )

[field_c] => Array
    (
        [type] => text
        [group_name] => 
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished by a simple `foreach` loop:

```
$start_array; // The array you want to convert
$end_array = array (); // The final array
foreach ($start_array as $index => $value) {
    if (empty($value["group_name"])) {
        $end_array[$index] = $value;
    } else {
        $end_array[$value["group_name"]][$index] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP needs arrays as values of destination array. With this you'll get only one value.

Answer (score -2):

If key order of new array is not so important:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value['group_name'])) $new_array[$key] = $value;
    else {
        if (!array_key_exists($value['group_name'], $new_array) $new_array[$value['group_name']] = array();
        $new_array[$value['group_name']][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
$array_dst = array();
foreach ($array_src as $group_key=>$group_data){
    $group_name = $group_data['group_name'];
    if (empty($array_dst[$group_name]))
        $array_dst[$group_name] = array();
    $array_dst[$group_name][$group_key] = $group_data;
}
```

Comment: you forgot, that entries without given `group_name` aren't inserted correctly with your solution

Comment: Why? :) It receives null value and inserted as usual. Try this `$array = array('group_name'=>'');
$name = $array['group_name'];
$new_array[$name] = 123;
var_dump($new_array);`

Answer (score -2):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach( $old_array as $field_id => $field ) {
    if( $field[ 'group_name' ] == '' ) {
       $new_array[ $field_id ] = $field;
    } else {
       $new_array[ $field[ 'group_name' ] ][ $field_id ] = $field;
    }
}
```

I suppose those who are down voting this are doing it because I am not initializing `$new_array[ $field[ 'group_name' ] ]`. Well, that is not necessary in PHP, it will be automatically initialized with an empty array when you do `$new_array[ $field[ 'group_name' ] ][ $field_id ] = $field;`.

Comment: you forgot, that entries without given `group_name` aren't inserted correctly with your solution